# How Upload Multiple files (images)(more than 100 files at a time) in mvc4?

Tags: image, image-processing, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all i ma working on mvc4 i had uploaded single image (file) but now i need to uoload more than 100 files(images) at time to my application how could i do this plz help to do this

here my code:
this is my controllers

```
[HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Uploading(ImageModel model)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {     
                    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    string serverPath = Server.MapPath("~");
                    string imagesPath = serverPath + "Content\\Images\\";
                    string thumsise = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "Thumb" + fileName);
                    string thumbPath = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "Thu" + fileName);
                    string fullPath = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "Full" + fileName);
                    string Bigpath = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "big" + fileName);
                    string Bigpatha = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "biga" + fileName);
                    string Bigpathb = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "bigb" + fileName);
                    string Bigpathc = Path.Combine(imagesPath, "bigc" + fileName );
                    ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(thumsise, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 80, true);
                    ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(thumbPath, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 100, true);
                    ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(fullPath, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 500, true);
                    ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(Bigpath, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 200, true);
                    ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(Bigpatha, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 250, true);
                    ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(Bigpathb, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 150, true);
                    ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(Bigpathc, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 50, true);
                }
                return View("Upload",model);
            }
```

this my class file:

```
public class ImageModel
    {

        [Required]

        public HttpPostedFileWrapper ImageUploaded { get; set; }
        public static void ResizeAndSave(string savePath, string fileName, Stream imageBuffer, int maxSideSize, bool makeItSquare)
        {
            int newWidth;
            int newHeight;
            Image image = Image.FromStream(imageBuffer);
            int oldWidth = image.Width;
            int oldHeight = image.Height;
            Bitmap newImage;
            if (makeItSquare)
            {
                int smallerSide = oldWidth >= oldHeight ? oldHeight : oldWidth;
                double coeficient = maxSideSize / (double)smallerSide;
                newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(coeficient * oldWidth);
                newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(coeficient * oldHeight);
                Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight);
                int cropX = (newWidth - maxSideSize) / 2;
                int cropY = (newHeight - maxSideSize) / 2;
                newImage = new Bitmap(maxSideSize, maxSideSize);
                Graphics tempGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
                tempGraphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                tempGraphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                tempGraphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                tempGraphic.DrawImage(tempImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, maxSideSize, maxSideSize), cropX, cropY, maxSideSize, maxSideSize, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            else
            {
                int maxSide = oldWidth >= oldHeight ? oldWidth : oldHeight;

                if (maxSide > maxSideSize)
                {
                    double coeficient = maxSideSize / (double)maxSide;
                    newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(coeficient * oldWidth);
                    newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(coeficient * oldHeight);
                }
                else
                {
                    newWidth = oldWidth;
                    newHeight = oldHeight;
                }
                newImage = new Bitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight);
            }
            newImage.Save(savePath + fileName + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            //newImage.Save(savePath + fileName + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            image.Dispose();
            newImage.Dispose();
        }  
    }
}
```

and this is my index page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploading", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
     {
         <input type="file" name="ImageUploaded" id="btnUpload" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"  />
     <button type="submit"  id="Upload">Upload</button>
         <br />
}
```

could u help me to upload more than 100 files at a time thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to upload a zip file with the images and then extract the images and parse them iteratively as required?

Comment: No i am not able to upload a zipfile even i dont have idea about it thanks for reply plz help me with more answers

Comment: Your answer will be in two parts. Firstly the uploading of multiple files and secondly the processing of the files. If you are wanting help with the first part then try using this jQuery control: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is OK. The problem is the controller: don't use ImageModel to get the file from the form. It restricts you to just one file. You can get multiple files through Request.Files property:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Request.Files[i].ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile = Request.Files[i];
                    ... here you can use the resize and other logic 
                    ... on uploadedFile.InputStream
                }
            }
```

Check the HttpPostedFileBase class. It's the base class for HttpPostedFileWrapper which you use in your ImageModel model class.

Comment: thanks Mr.Jparaya its working for me nice coding friend thanks alot